# Insert into table using multiple select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on creating stores procedure to insert values in table using select statement.
Following is my queuedemail table where i want to insert rows from two diffrent tables.

```
Id          int Unchecked
Priority    int Unchecked
[From]      nvarchar(500)   
FromName    nvarchar(500)   
[To]        nvarchar(500)   
ToName      nvarchar(500)   
CC          nvarchar(500)   
Bcc         nvarchar(500)   
Subject     nvarchar(1000)  
Body        nvarchar(MAX)
```

First table is campaign which is to be sent to customer

```
Id             int  
Name           nvarchar(MAX)    
Subject        nvarchar(MAX)    
Body           nvarchar(MAX)    
Sent           bit
```

I want to take body and subject from this campaign to insert in above table. and there are some tokens in the body which i want to replace with customer name.
Now customer values are going to come from customer tables which is having diffrent fields like name, email. Now to and toname in first table are going to come from this customer table.

Any suggestion.

Pardon if not understood. Leave comment if any!!!

Suppose I have customer table with 2 entries like

```
Id  F_Name    L_Name    Email 
1   Nitin     Varpe     fedexnit@gmail.com
2   Prashant  Bankar    pbankar@yahoo.com
```

Now i have campign having body like

Dear %Customer.Name%

//here goes body for the campaign

Now when I click send campaign. This token quoted in '%' going to be replaced with customer name.and then this body should be inserted in queuedemail table 'to' column by email of customer and toname same as customer name.

Thanx all for ur response.

Hoping to see more from u!!!

Comment: Could you post your tables and data what you want to insert?

Comment: Are these your source tables or destination tables? What is the query you have developed so far?

Comment: if **campaign** table and **customer** table have any relation then you can use joins to insert value in your **queuedemail** table. Otherwise use subquery.

Comment: @raj i tried with insert into using select but it returns as subquery returns more than one value error

Comment: @vikas no relation between customer and campaign

Comment: @Nitinvarpe then you have to insert value from subquery. Try to select only one value in subquery. e.g. **Select top 1 name from yourtable where id = 2**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
INSERT INTO queuedemail 
(
    FromName,
    To,
    Body
)
SELECT 
    F_Name,
    Email,
    'Dear' + F_Name +
    (
     SELECT body 
     FROM campaign 
     WHERE -- criteria for selecting body
    )

FROM customer 
WHERE -- your where condition criteria
```

Include the fields as your needs in insert and select clause

Answer (score 0):

where is customer name (which table) ?

What is relation between token and customer name.How you decide which token to be replace by which customer name .

first build your require select statement and verify each column and output .Decide about outer join/left/inner.

will %Customer.Name% several times in body part or only once.
will it be same  for every row ?
If  %Customer.Name% will be in every row and each body then this is quite easy
you can simply replace with Firstname+lastname.

Comment: Customer name is in table customer and email also

Answer (score 0):

Finally came up with solution. Thanx to all for ur support

Below is my stored procedure

Created temp table to get all the record from customer table.

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SendCampaign]    Script Date: 11/19/2013 14:40:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SendCampaign]
  (@CampaignSubject nvarchar(max),
  @CampaingBody nvarchar(max),
    @TotalRecords int OutPut)

AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   Declare @Body  nvarchar(max)=@CampaingBody
   Declare @Subject  nvarchar(max)=@CampaignSubject

   Select *
Into   #Temp
From   Customer where Active=1 

Select *from #Temp
   Declare @Id int


     Begin
Insert Into QueuedEmail([Priority],[From],FromName,[To],[ToName],CC,Bcc,
[Subject],[Body],CreatedonUtc,SentTries,SentonUtc,EmailAccountid,Attachment)

  Select  3,'test@test.com','My Site',Email,'Null','Null','Null',@Subject,
dbo.ModifyCampaign(@Body,CAST(NewsLetterSubscriptionGuid as NVARCHAR(200)),Email)
,GEtUtcDate(),0,null,4,'Null'
              from #Temp






     END
    Drop table #Temp

END
```

Above in select statement ModifyCampaign is the function i have written to replace tokens in campaign with corresponding customer details.

Thanx all :) and Hoping that it will help others in future